# AJAX Refresh Issues

Tags: javascript, html

I used the bottom code to refresh the page js.php without reloading the page . However the code i used was not working. Any way i can fix this?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <table style="border:1px solid black;">
    <tr>
    <th style="border:1px solid black;">Profit/Loss</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;"><?php echo $sumText ;?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>               
  var refreshInterval = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshInterval = setInterval(function(){
    $('#bid16').load('js.php');
  },2000);
});



</script>
<div id="bid16"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing a `<body>`

Comment: Hard to say what's going wrong without knowing what you've tried so far. Have you proven that `js.php` is actually running, and producing the output you expect?

Comment: A number of things have to be tried here. But for starters make your script tags <script type="text/javascript"> ... </script>. The JavaScirpt itself should be working. So it's either browser not recognizing the script zone or js.php not working properly.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Any errors? Are you trying to run this as a file?

Comment: There are no errors. I tried running it with text/javascript but it is not working. any ideas??

Comment: Body tags are being placed already , $sum text and all the rest of the variables in my code are being defined already..